# How does this "integration by differentiation" method work

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Apparently, the integral of a function f(x) from a to b can be done through differentiation through this method:
$$
  \int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{x \rightarrow  \ 0 }  f(\frac{d}{d x} )\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x}
$$
Can anyone explain why this works? We can assume that f has a MacLauren representation with an infinite radius of convergence.
An example with f(x) = c, c constant, the integral of f from a to b is:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow  \ 0 }  c\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x} = 
\lim_{x \rightarrow  \ 0 }  c\frac{1+bx+0.5(bx)^2...-1-ax-0.5(ax)^2...}{x} = c(b-a)
$$ as expected.

However I don't know how to show this is true for all (most?) functions with a MacLauren series. Help? The f(d/dx) and limit is what's being difficult to deal with. If f is something like x^2 then f(d/dx) is d^2/dx^2 but with a general function f I can't establish a pattern.

Comment: This is a very unusual method, to say the least. I've never seen it before. (And I'm assuming you need to write $f$ as a Taylor series, so that, for example, $e^{d/dx}=1+\dfrac d{dx}+\dfrac12\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+\dotsb$)

Comment: It's supposedly a newly discovered method.

Comment: Certainly creative and interesting. I suppose you only need to check it for powers $f(x)=x^n$, since Taylor says that everything else is just a combination of those.

Comment: (Also, when you checked with $f(x)=c$, you could've just used L'Hopital. Though, I suppose expanding it into a series probably makes checking the general case easier.)

Comment: This looks a litte bit like the procedure of shifting a wavefunction which in this case is just $ |a,b,x >= (e^{ax}-e^{bx})/x$ in quantum mechanics. Indeed, if f(x)=exp(i q x) this will just give you $|a,b,x-q >$ . Maybe you could look in this direction...

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.04348.pdf
for a really nice explanation and some examples.

Comment: Also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09702.pdf is an updated version of the above paper which includes even more examples applying this technique, and a more rigorous proof which assumes what's discussed above, namely, that f(x) has a Taylor's series whose radius of convergence includes [a, b].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For polynomials only, so not really an answer, but maybe one can take from here. Also, too long to put in a comment.

Let $f(x)=x^m$.

An expansion of $\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x}$ gives
$$
\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(b^n-a^n)x^{n-1}}{n!}
$$
Thus, there is only one term surviving (when $n=m+1$) when differentiating, and we get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\frac{e^{bx}-e^{ax}}{x}=\frac{b^{m+1}-a^{m+1}}{m+1}
$$
which agrees with $\int_a^b x^m\,dx$.

By linearity it works for all polynomials. For more general functions I guess one should be very precise what is meant by $f(d/dx)$.

Comment: Taylor says that all (analytic) functions are really just infinite polynomials, so I think that this is sufficient.

Comment: I agree with columbus, this is about sufficient. I stated that f can be written as a MacLauren series, so I can write f as a polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

How should we define $f(\frac{d}{ds})$ when $f$ is not a polynomial?  Probably the standard way to do it is with the Laplace transform.

Let's use this notation for the (bilateral) Laplace transform:  If $f(t)$ is a (nice enough) function, its Laplace transform is a function $F(s)$ defined by
$$
F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-ts}\;dt
$$
Write $F(s) = \mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}$ for the Laplace transform; and $f(t) = \mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}$ for the inverse Laplace transform.  I will attempt to use variables $s$ and $t$ consistently in this way.

If $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\} = F(s)$, then compute $\mathscr{L}\{-tf(t)\} = F'(s)$.  By induction, $\mathscr{L}\{(-t)^kf(t\}) = F^{(k)}(s)$ for natural number $k$.  By linearity, $\mathscr{L}\{\phi(-t)f(t)\} = \phi(\frac{d}{ds})F(s)$ for any polynomial $\phi$.

**Define** $\phi(\frac{d}{ds})$ for non-polynomials $\phi$ using the same formula.  Thus
$$
\phi\left(\frac{d}{ds}\right)F(s) = \mathscr{L}\big\{\phi(-t)f(t)\big\}
=\mathscr{L}\left\{\phi(-t)\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\right\}
\tag{*}$$
Of course you need conditions for all these to exist.  When $f$ is bounded, measurable, with compact support, there is no problem at all.

Now to this question.  Fix $a < b$ real numbers.  Let $\phi$ be the function to integrate from $a$ to $b$.  Define function $h(t)$ by
$$
h(t) = \begin{cases}0\quad\text{if } t<-b
\\1\quad\text{if } -b \le t \le -a
\\0\quad\text{if } -a < t\end{cases} .
$$
This is bounded, measurable, with compact support.
Compute
$$
\mathscr{L}\{h(t)\} = \frac{e^{sb}-e^{sa}}{s} .
$$
Thus with definition $(*)$ we have
$$
\phi\left(\frac{d}{ds}\right) \frac{e^{sb}-e^{sa}}{s}= 
\mathscr{L}\{\phi(-t)h(t)\} =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(-t)h(t)e^{-st}\;dt
\\
=\int_{-b}^{-a}\phi(-t)e^{-st}\,dt = \int_a^b \phi(x) e^{sx}\;dx .
$$
(We changed variables $t=-x$.)

And thus
$$
\lim_{s \to 0}\phi\left(\frac{d}{ds}\right) \frac{e^{sb}-e^{sa}}{s}= 
\int_a^b\phi(x)\;dx .
$$

Comment: It's not entirely clear what it means $f(\frac{d}{dx})$. What is it all about?